# How to check the radio buttons using the value of a hidden field with Mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an attribute of type int called "TypeOfProperty" in a model. There are several radio buttons on view page.I want to check the corresponding radio buttons(Like "Appartment", "plot" etc) on the basis of the value of "TypeOfProperty".

```
 @Html.RadioButton("Appartment", @Model.TypeOfProperty.Equals("1"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how the `RadioButton` helper works. If you have `int TypeOfProperty` and you want to post back the selected value, then it would be something like

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TypeOfProperty, "1")<span>Apartment</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TypeOfProperty, "2")<span>Plot</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TypeOfProperty, "3")<span>Another type</span>
```

The if the value of `TypeOfProperty` is 2, the second radio button will be selected. If the user chooses the first radio button, then `TypeOfProperty` will be posted back with the value 1.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller's action you can run this code to get the value of `@Model.TypeOfProperty.Equals("1")`

```
Request.Form["Appartment"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.RadioButton("Appartment",@Model.TypeOfProperty, @Model.TypeOfProperty.Equals("1"))
```

The third parameter is `isChecked`.  The radio will be selected if this expression evaluates to true.